# Update attributes of directive template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, datepicker

I'm writing a directive for [Bootstrap Datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/). It require `data-date` attribute as start date for calendar. However in my interfase there are another selectors for month and year. So I need somehow to rerender template for this directive  each time year and month will be changed in main controller. I thougnt to use jQuery.attr inside linking function to add corresponding attributes. But `link` gets executed only once.

Here is how I use it

```
<li datepicker ng-model="results.config.filters" class="filter" ng-class="{active:ngModel.day}">
```

And here is directive itself.

```
window.DatePickerDirective = ->
  restrict: "A"
  scope:
    ngModel: '='
  link: (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) ->
    date = new Date()
    if scope.ngModel.year
      date.setYear scope.ngModel.year
    if scope.ngModel.month
      date.setMonth scope.ngModel.year
    $(elem).attr 'data-date', [scope.ngModel.month, 1, scope.ngModel.year].join('/')
    dp = $(elem).datepicker().on('changeDate', (ev) ->
      scope.$apply ->
        scope.ngModel.day = ev.date
      dp.hide()
    ).data('datepicker')
```

How can i handle this?

Comment: you can put a watch on 'month+year' using scope.$watch and update the dom inside watch

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal, inside directive???

Comment: yes you can use $watch inside a directive

Comment: You guys make this answer, I'll accept it. It work and now I even found this solution obvious.